# Solr sorting issue

Tags: java, ruby, sorting, solr, lucene

I am getting this weird error message  `can not sort on multivalued field: fieldname` on all the indexed fields. This is the full error message from solr

```
</head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - can not sort on multivalued field: price</h1><hr/><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b>can not sort on multivalued field: price</p><p><b>description</b>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (can not sort on multivalued field: price).</p><hr/><h3>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1</h3></body></html>
```

I am sure that my indexed field doesnt have `multiValued=true` set on

```
 <field name="price" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multivalued="false" />
```

to make sure that i have added `multiValued=false`, but i am still getting the same error.

This is the URL request sent to solr

```
http://localhost:8080/apache-solr-3.1.0/select?wt=ruby&q=flat&fl=_id&sort=price+asc&limit=5&offset=0
```

and relevant rsolr call

```
res = solr.get 'select', :params => {
              :q =>'flat',
              :fl => "_id",
              :sort=>'price asc',
              'limit' => 5,
              'offset' => 0
          }
```

It all works fine if i remove the sort from the request.

Can some one help me out..

**PS:** I do have only one multivalued field in the document, but thats not used in the sort

**Update**:

Here the complete stack-trace from solr log

```
[#|2011-12-06T16:03:35.813+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: can not sort on multivalued field: price
    at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.checkSortability(SchemaField.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.getSortField(TrieField.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.getSortField(SchemaField.java:144)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QueryParsing.parseSort(QueryParsing.java:385)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getSort(QParser.java:251)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:102)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1372)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2011-12-06T16:03:35.814+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|[] webapp=/apache-solr-3.5.0 path=/select params={wt=ruby&q=flat&fl=_id&sort=price+asc&limit=5&offset=0} status=400 QTime=42 |#]
```

**Update2:**

As suggested by @Mateg i got the field details from the schema page. see below

```
Field: price
Field Type: FLOAT

Properties: Indexed, Tokenized, Stored, Multivalued, Omit Norms

Schema: Indexed, Tokenized, Stored, Multivalued, Omit Norms

Index: Indexed, Tokenized, Stored, Omit Norms

Index Analyzer: org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain DETAILS

Query Analyzer: org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain DETAILS
```

It says the price field is `tokenized` and `multivalued`. Its interesting not only this field is like that, all other field are also multivalued.

Comment: which solr version do you use? can you post a dump of your solr log file? maybe just the WARNINGS or SEVERE lines. stumbling arount the internet i found out this could be a solr4j library problem (as in not correctly installed/included). are you using a custom made plugin?

Comment: i am using solr 3.1.. now  i am going to try with 3.5 and let you know the results.. i am calling it from ruby using rsolr gem

Comment: maybe it's a "value" error: if there's a "," in the number (say 100,3) solr reads it as a multivalued (i had the same problem with non multivalued texts, and solved it adding a CDATA tag around the field value)

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo, i have added the error log from the solr. please have a look. And i have tried with lastest solr release 3.5 too. the same error occurs.. Also i have verified for the commas,  both price & created_at fields doesnt have any commas..

Comment: check this link if it can help: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrGlassfish they say that solr and glassfish have problems handling utf8 get requests (encoding is completed but still 404 returns)

Comment: Maybe you have field price defined twice? Check with schema browser from Solr admin.

Comment: @Matej, no. Its not defined twice. In fact price is not the only field gicing the error. All other indexed fields also giving the same error

Comment: are you sure you restarted Solr after making any changes to the schema or config?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, yeah, restarted the solr instance and glassfish server also the system.. nothing works.. really struck here

Comment: Can you print out price field details from `admin/schema.jsp`

Comment: @Matej, just added the field drtails. see the post.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all index files and re-index all your content. It seems that your data is not consistent with schema.

Comment: @Matej, i finally found the problem. check my answer. The problem is with schema versioning. its total nightmare...thanks for helping me narrow down the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What a day , I finally found the problem after long struggle. Thanks to everyone

- First of all i am not aware of setting the  `version number in schema file`.   As per the documentation default value for multi value is false from the version 1.1

> ```
>    1.0: multiValued attribute did not exist, all fields are multiValued by nature
>    1.1: multiValued attribute introduced, false by default
> ```

But i was using the old schema file with the version 1.0. So all fields are set to multiValued by default.

Every time i upgraded the solr, i just copy pasted the old schema file.

Now it works fine after changing this to the current version 1.4.

```
  <schema name="ItemSearch" version="1.4">
```

Comment: In solr version 5.0.0 you can find an example schema with the correct version in `solr/example/example-DIH/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml` and you'll see something like `<schema name="example-DIH-solr" version="1.5">`